# Use of local variable 'displayAlert' before its declaration

Tags: ios, swift

I have called function and It isn't still displaying the code right I have been receiving and error Use of local variable 'displayAlert' before its declaration

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// I have also switched the @IBAction to function so the code actually run better any suggestions to fix this 

@IBOutlet weak var dropoffLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickupLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pickupDropoffSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var buttomButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var topButton: UIButton!

var signUpMode = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func topTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if emailTextfield.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" {
        code error coming from here ----> displayAlert(title: "Missing Information", message: "You must provide both a email and password")
    } else {
        if let email = emailTextfield.text {
            if let password = passwordTextField.text {
                if signUpMode {
                    // SIGN UP
                    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            displayAlert(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            print("Sign Up Success")
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    // LOG IN
                    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            displayAlert(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            print("Sign Up Success")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ------> I believe if I am doing it correctly called the function here func displayAlert(title:String, message:String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    //there is no other issue besides the code not understanding the the function I have labeled 
    //Also I have ran the code before and the alert would pop up but now it is not allowing the 

    func buttomTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if signUpMode {
            topButton.setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
            buttomButton.setTitle("Switch to Sign Up", for: .normal)
            pickupLabel.isHidden = true
            dropoffLabel.isHidden = true
            pickupDropoffSwitch.isHidden = true
            signUpMode = false
        } else {
            topButton.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
            buttomButton.setTitle("Switch to Log In", for: .normal)
            pickupLabel.isHidden = false
            dropoffLabel.isHidden = false
            pickupDropoffSwitch.isHidden = false
            signUpMode = true
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You are calling a function `displayAlert` but presumably you haven't defined that function anywhere.

Comment: Where is your displayAlert function?

Comment: Please mention you full code.

Comment: I have mentioned the full code above @aBilal17

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly defined your displayAlert func inside the topTapped func.

You need to move it outside so it is on the class level

```
@IBAction func topTapped(_ sender: Any) {
//code here
}

func displayAlert(title:String, message:String) {
//
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that but it continues to leave the error ant other suggestions

Comment: Could you update the code then in your question so we see what you currently have a problem with. And remove the text before displayAlert so the code compiles.